# Why are subclasses not initialized in Rails Single Table Inheritance?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, single-table-inheritance

I'm trying to make a simple "book signing" app on Rails (books, authors, bookstores, etc.) using single table inheritance (`class Bookstore < Company`).

I have the following in config/application.rb:

`config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}.app/models/company)`

Both company.rb and bookstore.rb are in the app/models/company directory.

`Bookstore.create(name: "Barnes and Noble")` is in seeds.rb

When I run `rails db:seed` I get an error `uninitialized constant Bookstore`

Also if I'm in the rails console and I do `Bookstore.new(...)`, I get the same error, but if I do `Company.new(...)` I get `undefined method 'new' for Company:Module` which was surprising because I thought Company was a class:

company.rb has `class Company < ApplicationRecord`

How do I set up single table inheritance so that I can store classes in sub directories?

I'm using rails 5.2

Thanks!

Comment: Put the classes in `app/models` instead of `app/models/company`

Comment: I don't want them there, that folder is too crowded.  I want to know if there is a way to put the files in subdirectories

Comment: Rails automatically loads models from subfolders but would expect them to have a namespace, so if `Bookstore` is in `app/models/company` you would write `class Company::Bookstore`

Comment: A note about "too crowded" -- the solution should not be "just put it somewhere else", as that only serves to make a part of a whole harder to find. The solution is to refactor and tease out a meaningful abstraction in its entirety, thus truly making that previous whole "smaller".

Comment: @benjessop does that mean that the type column in the companies table will have things like Company::Bookstore?  Is there a way around that?

Comment: @A.Pizzle Yes, you'll need the `Company::` part in the type

Comment: I think that's what I did; there will be many different types of Company

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there's a typo:

`config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}.app/models/company)`

should be

`config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/app/models/company)`

=> slash in front of the app directory instead of a dot

Answer (score 0):

If you want to nest your models in a namespace you would do it like so:

```
class Company
end

# app/modules/companies/bookstore.rb
module Companies
  class Bookstore < ::Company
  end
end

# app/modules/companies/cafe.rb
module Companies
  class Cafe < ::Company
  end
end
```

The reason you would want to use a separate constant for the namespace and not reopen the constant `Company` is the the [numerous bugs and issues](https://blog.jetbrains.com/ruby/2017/03/why-you-should-not-use-a-class-as-a-namespace-in-rails-applications/) with the classic autoloader used in Rails 5.2 and module nesting in classes.

While you could append paths to the autoloader its just seems silly to forgo the additional code organization that module nesting gives you. Its not like polluting the global namespace is a great thing to do.